# When and Why an xml layout tag should instantial an object of a class?

Tags: android, xml

I do not know when to let an xml layout tag instantiate an object of a class and why it is sometime essential to do so. I just need explanation or any guide or tutorial please.

Example:

```
<com.example.camerasurface.CustomCameraView
    android:id="@+id/surfaceView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clickable="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets just keep it simple and say that whatever you do in the XML file is HARD CODED.

It wont change throughout the entire application.
So whatever you want hardcoded constant in your site you declare in the XML.

The rest of dynamic stuff can happen in java.

Hope this helps.

Comment: any tutorial? i search google for "xml layout instantiate an object" but the results were useless

Comment: There is no tutorial for what you can instantiate in XML. Its users preference.

Comment: It is most probably layout related values because they dont change the entire app.